# What is the risk of enabling EKS encryption on existing production cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I have a EKS cluster running on production which does not enable encryption.

I would like to ask if there's any risk such as downtime, changes in using existing secret or other notable risks that would occur if I enable?

I've read from this doc. It said:

> No changes in the way you’re using secrets are required, all that is
> necessary is to enable the encryption provider support on cluster
> create. (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/using-eks-encryption-provider-support-for-defense-in-depth/)

[image]

Refering to the document it should not affect the existing cluster. I'm not sure if it is really safe.

And if anything goes wrong, can it be rollback/disable?

Comment: RE if anything goes wrong, [**You can't disable secrets encryption after enabling it. This action is irreversible.**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/update-cluster.html#enable-kms)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to ensure the key is multi-region enabled, access to the key is controlled and key policy will not be undermine.